# File updating on S3 file store failure via rails3/carrierwave/fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I use separate remote storage based on amazon s3 for images. 
Updating records via activeadmin I have encountered unknown error 
during image updating. That wasn't rails error with stacktrace
but some sort of timeout occured in stage environment.

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',             
    :aws_access_key_id      => APP['s3']['key'],      
    :aws_secret_access_key  => APP['s3']['secret'],   
  }
  config.fog_directory    = 'mdfile'  
  config.fog_public       = false   
  config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 5

  config.cache_dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 's3', Rails.env)  
end
```

app/uploaders/news_image_uploader.rb

```
class NewsImageUploader < Mdfile::BaseUploader
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :resize_to_fill => [150, 112]
  process convert: 'png'

  def extension_white_list
    APP['upload']['image_white_list']
  end

  def fog_public
    true
  end

  def filename
    "image.png" if original_filename
  end
end
```

app/uploaders/mdfile/base_uploader.rb

```
module Mdfile
  class BaseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    before :store, :remember_cache_id
    before :cache, :remove_old_file_before_cache

    def remember_cache_id(new_file)
      @cache_id_was = cache_id
    end

    def remove_old_file_before_cache(new_file)
      remove! unless blank?
    end

    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    def filename
      if original_filename 
        @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path))
        "#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

All images assigned to models (News, Articles) are storted on remote s3 on special path: uploads/stage/article/image/691/image.png

I've made research and ran rails with EXCON_DEBUG=true for logging requests and responses between s3 and my host.
As ascertained

**on creation of new record:**

Excon sends one PUT-request dumped below

```
excon.request  {:chunk_size=>1048576, :connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog/1.9.0", "Content-Length"=>37593, "Content-Type"=>"image/jpeg", "x-amz-acl"=>"public-read", "Date"=>"Wed, 14 Aug 2013 08:49:52 +0000", "Authorization"=>"REDACTED", "Host"=>"mdfile.s3.amazonaws.com:443"}, :idempotent=>true, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :nonblock=>true, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"mdfile.s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/uploads%2Fdevelopment%2Fnews%2Fimage%2F692%2Fimage.png", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>"REDACTED", :instrumentor=>Excon::StandardInstrumentor, :body=>#<File:/local/path/to/cached/file/20130814-1249-6113-6726/Reaktor.jpg>, :expects=>200, :method=>"PUT", :retries_remaining=>4 }

excon.response  {:body=>"", :headers=>{ "Date"=>"Wed, 14 Aug 2013 08:49:53 GMT", "Content-Length"=>"0", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>200, :remote_ip=>"[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]"}
```

*I cut some private and useless fields.*

**on updating of existing record:**

Excon sends one DELETE-request for erasing old image, 
then it sends GET-request for path="/" (wtf!! ) and falls to endless loop of GET-requests and successful responses.

```
excon.request  {:chunk_size=>1048576, :connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog/1.9.0", "Date"=>"Wed, 14 Aug 2013 08:56:47 +0000", "Authorization"=>"REDACTED", "Host"=>"mdfile.s3.amazonaws.com:443"}, :idempotent=>true, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"mdfile.s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/uploads%2Fdevelopment%2Fnews%2Fimage%2F692%2Fimage.png", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>"REDACTED", :family=>0, :expects=>204, :method=>"DELETE", :retries_remaining=>4, :connection=>#<Excon::Connection:b2ee900 @data={:chunk_size=>1048576, :connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog/1.9.0"}, :idempotent=>false, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :instrumentor=>Excon::StandardInstrumentor, :family=>0} @socket_key="s3.amazonaws.com:443">, :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :instrumentor=>Excon::StandardInstrumentor, :family=>0} @socket_key="s3.amazonaws.com:443">>>>>}

excon.response  {:body=>"", :headers=>{"Date"=>"Wed, 14 Aug 2013 08:56:48 GMT", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>204, :remote_ip=>"[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]"}

excon.request  {:chunk_size=>1048576, :connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog/1.9.0", "Date"=>"Wed, 14 Aug 2013 08:56:48 +0000", "Authorization"=>"REDACTED", "Host"=>"s3.amazonaws.com:443"}, :idempotent=>true, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>"REDACTED", :instrumentor=>Excon::StandardInstrumentor, :family=>0, :expects=>200, :method=>"GET", :url=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"/", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :instrumentor=>Excon::StandardInstrumentor, :family=>0} @socket_key="s3.amazonaws.com:443">}

excon.response  {:body=>"", :headers=>{"Date"=>"Wed, 14 Aug 2013 08:56:50 GMT", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>200, :remote_ip=>"[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]"}
```

So I can stop rails process on localhost via kill -9

Then I clarified that such behaviour occured for update_attribute(s) method of model (News,Articles...) which invokes CarrierWave logic.

**Question**: why does carrierwave/fog make weird GET-request and rolls down to endless loop

- rails 3.2.14
- activeadmin 0.5.1
- inherited_resources 1.4.1
- carrierwave 0.8.0
- fog 1.9.0
- excon 0.20.1

**Update**:
I've found out if I update uploader's column ('image' in my case) with nil value before update attribute, than correct PUT-request is sent to s3. So bugfixing code for activeadmin controller is:

```
controller do

  def update
    resource_object = resource_class
    @object = resource_object.find(params[:id])
    object_sym = resource_class.to_s.downcase.to_sym
    @object.update_column(:image, nil) if @object.respond_to?(:image) && params[object_sym][:image].present?
    update!
  end

end
```

But question is still topical.